# Can I create post without submitted-url in case of content having title

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

```
var jsonBody = {
    "comment": jsonData.comment,  
    "content": {
        "title": jsonData.title ? jsonData.title:'',
        "description": jsonData.desc ? jsonData.desc : '',
        "submitted-url":jsonData.contenUrl ? jsonData.contenUrl : '',
        "submitted-image-url": jsonData.contentImageUrl ? jsonData.contentImageUrl : ''
    },
    "visibility": {
        "code": _visibleTo
    }
}

var url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json';

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-li-format': 'json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonBody)
};


request(options, function (err, response) {
    if (JSON.parse(response.body).status) {
        res.send({data: JSON.parse(response.body).message});
    } else {
        res.send('success');
    }
});
```

Its working  with/without full content data, but if I mention title  in content its throwing error submmited url required, is it possible to post without submitted url in case content having only title

Comment: can you post an example of a title that throws an error ?

Comment: If this   "content": {
        "title": "Test'',
        "description": "Testing '',
        "submitted-url":" '',
        "submitted-image-url": jsonData.contentImageUrl ? jsonData.contentImageUrl : ''
    }, doen't  have submitted-url  it is throwing error "submitted-url missing" but If dont have content json data at all it will post with submit url also works

Comment: I see you've written `"submitted-url":jsonData.contenUrl ? jsonData.contenUrl : '',`  are you sure it is not jsonData.conten**__t__**Url ?

Comment: Sure , Its working when I have submitted url in json data